# Real Time Burst IO Balance on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, performance, storage

I'm trying to troubleshoot some disk performance issues on an ec2 instance using a 60 GiB gp2 volume.  The cloud watch metrics don't seem very fine grained.  Is there a way to view in real time the burst balance, e.g. by tailing some file when ssh'ed into the machine?

Comment: Consider asking a question about the problem you are trying to solve, [instead of](http://xyproblem.info) about the way you are trying to solve it.  Either you have a significant amount of available EBS burst balance, or you don't, and real-time access to this stat would be unlikely to be of significant value, even if it were available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, because these metrics do not originate from within the instance.  The burst balance is maintained by EBS, not EC2.  Where, exactly, in the infrastructure it is calculated is not documented, but it is external to your VM, in any event.

Observing I/O with high granularity from inside your instance can be done with `iostat`.  I find the arguments `-x 1` to be useful.  The % metric at the far right gives you an indication of your instance's perception of how hard it is driving the volume based on wait times.

Numbers near 100% mean you are saturating *something* though that something is a complex combination of factors.  When an EBS volume was created from a snapshot and is still warming up, it is common to see near 100% utilization even though you are only seeing 5 to 10 MB/s of throughput, because what you are saturating is the warmup process inside EBS (which loads blocks onto the volume from the snapshot data; this background task is what allows large volumes to be created so quickly from snapshots -- the data is logically on the new volume, but may not be physically on the new volume, yet).   Saturating your instance's Ethernet bandwidth to EBS will also cause high % values, even though the volume itself has idle capacity available.

---

Bonus: here's a little one-liner I came up with to make `iostat` show something more like a "console" view rather than continuously scrolling the screen.  It uses the system perl to add some ansi escape sequences to reformat the output.  Works as written on Ubuntu, and presumably on Amazon Linux as well.  Running `iostat` seems to impose essentially no meaningful load of its own on the system, so should be safe to use on any server.

```
iostat -x 1 | perl -pe 'BEGIN { $_ = 1; print "\e[1;1H\e[0J" } print "\e[3;1H" if /^avg\-cpu/; chomp; $_ .= "\e[0K\n"'
```